# Best strategy to process the structure data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data store in .cfg file as

```
Name: ABC
Age: 50
Height: 170
Weight: 60
City: Cali
```

I am using python and I want to find the way to process the file and access it. Currently, I use  the read as txt file but it may not good solution. This is my current solution:

```
data = [line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in open(info.cfg)]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: please clarify: are you looking for a suitable format to store data or a suitable way to parse a certain format?

Comment: @hjpotter92: I tried it but it never work

Comment: If you convert the config file to yaml notation the handling would become quite easy

Comment: configparser uses the equals symbol for key value pairs rather than colon, the. Cfg file is more like yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example input, [`yaml`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) might be a suitable file format. You could easily import it to `dict` like

```py
import yaml
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    cfg = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

cfg
Out[20]: {'Name': 'ABC', 'Age': 50, 'Height': 170, 'Weight': 60, 'City': 'Cali'}
```

You can now access individual keys as

```py
cfg['Weight']
Out[21]: 60
```

Comment: Great solution. How to access the weight value?

Comment: @MoonLee: added an example.

Comment: You can use `cfg["Weight"]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to firstly modify your config file. Add a header

```
[header_name]
Name: ABC
Age: 50
Height: 170
Weight: 60
City: Cali
```

**Answer**

```
import configparser
configParser = configparser.RawConfigParser()   
configFilePath = 'config_file_name.cfg'
configParser.read(configFilePath)
print('Height : ',dict(configParser.items('header_name'))['height'])
```